# Cannot create Servlet in IntelliJ Ultimate Edition

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I cannot create servlet using `New -> Servlet` in IntelliJ IDEA. Of course it's Ultimate edition; I've marked `src/main/java` as source root directory but I still cannot create it automatically. Only option left is to create it manually as I did.

Comment: Does it work from "Web" tool window?

Comment: @y.bedrov Yeah it works from "Web' tool window.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I'm stucking in here and still couldn't figure out. The two solutions I tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting a bit and came across a scenario, may be it help you.
I created a directory main\java, which was created as a maven source directories as suggested by Intellij by default as shown in image.[image: main\java]
Then i marked src as source directory and i do not get option to create new servlet under created java directory.
So in this particular case if you want to create servlet then first go to, "Mark directory as > Unmark as sources root".
Now you can create servlet inside java directory as well.

Comment: Also you can try out by updating maven project. Go to, "View> Tools Windows> Maven" then try,"Reimport All Maven Projects and Generate Sources and Update Folders For All Projects"

Answer (score 1):

Open `Project Structure` and select `Modules`.
You should see a list of all your project modules. The module where you want to create a `Servlet` in should have a [Web Facet](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/web-facet-page.html). If not, read [enabling-web-application-support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-web-application-support.html).

Every source route that contains your web application Java classes should be attached as source route to your web facet. That can be done on the web facet page.

After attaching all source routes the `Create New Servlet` option should be available the `New` menu.

Comment: Not "Project Settings" but "Project Structure".

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are missing the servlet jar, if you are using the Idea Ultimate with maven then you can add the servlet dependency to it, I use embedded tomcat which adds the servlet itself

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.55</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

**first :** *right click src\java > Mark directory as > source root*

**second :** *go to file > Project Structure > Facets > click Web(project name), then check src\main\java under source root.*

[image: Screnshot]

Answer (score 1):

First mark your source folder as root source folder.

Then make sure that in  file > Project Structure > Facets > click Web(project name) *src\main\java* is under source root.

If problem not solved check your pom.xml file in maven and make sure you have *Java Servlet API* dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I will just write my solution here. I had the same issue turned out all i needed to do was to scroll down once i right click on java source folder. The menu create new servlet should appear at the bottom below the data source section